# OLE DB source of oracle isn't updated after the provider was changed in ssis project

Tags: ssis, oledb

i create new project of ssis integration service
I have an OLE DB Source that connected to oracle provider.
I created package configuration file and change the server name and password.
the provider in the package was changed to the new server,but the OLE DB Source wasn't update...

do you know why?
thanks
zipi

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you didn't properly setup your configuration file and configuration for your package to actually read from the configuration file in order to use the proper connection string.

However, more details are required.

Comment: i also updated the OLE DB Destination that connected to sql provider and its work.